# Copy attachments from records in one recordset into records in another using VBA in MS Access

Tags: vba, microsoft-access, microsoft-office-2016

I've almost got this working.  I'm thinking I really just need another set of eyes on this.  I think my problem is just a simple programming structure issue.  Either too many loops or opening/closing recordsets in the wrong order.

I'm attempting to copy all of the attachment files contained in records from one dao recordset into corresponding records in another dao recordset.  Both recordsets are pulling data from the same table. The first recordset (rstOld) contains records with a date value from last year and those records could contain any number of attachments.  The second recordset (rstNew) contains records with a date value from this year and those records do not contain any attachments.

To accomplish this I start a loop through each record in rstNew.  For each record in rstNew I'll gather the value of the Name field and then start a second loop.  The second loop will find a record in rstOld with a matching Name field.  From there I just need to copy all the attachments from the record in rstOld to the record in rstNew.

The weird thing is that it'll work correctly on the first first record in rstNew that it finds a match.  After that it no longer work for any subsequent records.

Here's my code so far:

```
    Dim db As Database
    Dim strOldSQL As String
    Dim rstOld As DAO.Recordset2
    Dim strNewSQL As String
    Dim rstNew As DAO.Recordset2
    Dim rstOldAttachments As DAO.Recordset2
    Dim rstNewAttachments As DAO.Recordset2
    Dim strCurrentSiteName As String
    Dim strOldSiteName As String
Set db = CurrentDb()

    'First let's open a recordset that contains all of the records from this year.
    strNewSQL = "SELECT tblAuditForms.SiteName, tblAuditForms.Attachments, tblAuditForms.AuditYear FROM tblAuditForms WHERE AuditYear = #" & Format(cboMyDate, "mm/dd/yyyy") & "# ORDER By tblAuditForms.SiteName;"
    Set rstNew = db.OpenRecordset(strNewSQL)
    rstNew.MoveFirst
    rstNew.Edit
    
    Do While Not rstNew.EOF 'Now we need to loop through these records.
    
        strCurrentSiteName = rstNew.Fields("SiteName").Value 'Get the name of the site for the current record that we're on. We'll use this to compare with the sites in the previous audit.
                    
        'Now let's open a recordset that contains all records from the previous audit.
        strOldSQL = "SELECT tblAuditForms.SiteName, tblAuditForms.Attachments, Year([AuditYear]) FROM tblAuditForms WHERE Year([AuditYear]) = " & Me.cboPreviousDate & " ORDER BY tblAuditForms.SiteName;"
        Set rstOld = db.OpenRecordset(strOldSQL)
        rstOld.MoveFirst
        
        Do While Not rstOld.EOF 'Loop through each of the records from the previous audit until we find a record that matches the current site name.
        
            strOldSiteName = rstOld.Fields("SiteName").Value
        
            If strCurrentSiteName = strOldSiteName Then 'If this is true, then we've found a record from the previous audit that matches the one from our current audit.
                'Now it's just a matter of copying the attachments from the old record into the new one.  Working with attachments is annoying though.
                
                'This next block should loop through the attachments (if any) in the old record and copy them into the new record.
                Set rstOldAttachments = rstOld.Fields("Attachments").Value
                rstOldAttachments.MoveFirst
                
                Set rstNewAttachments = rstNew.Fields("Attachments").Value

                Do While Not rstOldAttachments.EOF
                    
                    rstNewAttachments.AddNew
                    rstNewAttachments.Fields("FileData").Value = rstOldAttachments.Fields("FileData").Value
                    rstNewAttachments.Fields("FileName").Value = rstOldAttachments.Fields("FileName").Value
                    rstNewAttachments.Fields("FileType").Value = rstOldAttachments.Fields("FileType").Value
                    rstNewAttachments.Update
                
                    rstOldAttachments.MoveNext
                Loop
                
                'Now that we've found the site from the previous audit and copied its attachments into the new record we can close the old recordset and move onto the next site in the current audit.
                rstOldAttachments.Close
                rstNewAttachments.Close
                Exit Do
            
            End If
                        
            rstOld.MoveNext
        Loop
         
        rstOld.Close
        rstNew.Update
        rstNew.MoveNext
    Loop
        
    'If we've gotten this far then we've looped through all of the new records that we just created from the weekly staffing workbook.
    rstNew.Close
```

Like I said before, this code will work on the first loop through the rstNew recordset, but it doesn't work on any subsequent loops.  Am I breaking out of a loop too soon? or closing a recordset too early?

Comment: Have you tried using the debugger?

Comment: @DavidPostill, yeah, I'm using the debugger and stepping through each loop, but I'm still not seeing where it's going wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've figured it out!  I knew I was close.  I've learned that once you've executed the recordset.update (or in my case rstNew.update) statement, the recordset editmode property goes back to 0.  This would explain why it would successfully copy the attachments the first loop around but fail on any subsequent loops.  So all I had to do was move the "rstNew.Edit" statement directly above the "Set rstNewAttachments = rstNew.Fields("Attachments").Value" line.

Here's what the new code looks like:

```
    Dim db As Database
    Dim strOldSQL As String
    Dim rstOld As DAO.Recordset2
    Dim strNewSQL As String
    Dim rstNew As DAO.Recordset2
    Dim rstOldAttachments As DAO.Recordset2
    Dim rstNewAttachments As DAO.Recordset2
    Dim strCurrentSiteName As String
    Dim strOldSiteName As String
Set db = CurrentDb()

    'First let's open a recordset that contains all of the records from this year.
    strNewSQL = "SELECT tblAuditForms.SiteName, tblAuditForms.Attachments, tblAuditForms.AuditYear FROM tblAuditForms WHERE AuditYear = #" & Format(cboMyDate, "mm/dd/yyyy") & "# ORDER By tblAuditForms.SiteName;"
    Set rstNew = db.OpenRecordset(strNewSQL)
    rstNew.MoveFirst
        
    Do While Not rstNew.EOF 'Now we need to loop through these records.
    
        strCurrentSiteName = rstNew.Fields("SiteName").Value 'Get the name of the site for the current record that we're on. We'll use this to compare with the sites in the previous audit.
                    
        'Now let's open a recordset that contains all records from the previous audit.
        strOldSQL = "SELECT tblAuditForms.SiteName, tblAuditForms.Attachments, Year([AuditYear]) FROM tblAuditForms WHERE Year([AuditYear]) = " & Me.cboPreviousDate & " ORDER BY tblAuditForms.SiteName;"
        Set rstOld = db.OpenRecordset(strOldSQL)
        rstOld.MoveFirst
        
        Do While Not rstOld.EOF 'Loop through each of the records from the previous audit until we find a record that matches the current site name.
        
            strOldSiteName = rstOld.Fields("SiteName").Value
        
            If strCurrentSiteName = strOldSiteName Then 'If this is true, then we've found a record from the previous audit that matches the one from our current audit.
                'Now it's just a matter of copying the attachments from the old record into the new one.  Working with attachments is annoying though.
                
                'This next block should loop through the attachments (if any) in the old record and copy them into the new record.
                Set rstOldAttachments = rstOld.Fields("Attachments").Value
                rstOldAttachments.MoveFirst
                
                rstNew.Edit
                Set rstNewAttachments = rstNew.Fields("Attachments").Value

                Do While Not rstOldAttachments.EOF
                    
                    rstNewAttachments.AddNew
                    rstNewAttachments.Fields("FileData").Value = rstOldAttachments.Fields("FileData").Value
                    rstNewAttachments.Fields("FileName").Value = rstOldAttachments.Fields("FileName").Value
                    rstNewAttachments.Fields("FileType").Value = rstOldAttachments.Fields("FileType").Value
                    rstNewAttachments.Update
                
                    rstOldAttachments.MoveNext
                Loop
                
                'Now that we've found the site from the previous audit and copied its attachments into the new record we can close the old recordset and move onto the next site in the current audit.
                rstOldAttachments.Close
                rstNewAttachments.Close
                Exit Do
            
            End If
                        
            rstOld.MoveNext
        Loop
         
        rstOld.Close
        rstNew.Update
        rstNew.MoveNext
    Loop
        
    'If we've gotten this far then we've looped through all of the new records that we just created from the weekly staffing workbook.
    rstNew.Close
```